# cannot edit any php files using specific functions

Tags: php, permissions, text-files

I cannot update any txt files using php. When I write a simple code like the following:

```
<?php 

// create file pointer 
$fp = fopen("C:/Users/jj/bob.txt", 'w') or die('Could not open file, or fike does not                exist and failed to create.'); 

$mytext = '<b>hi. This is my test</b>'; 

// write text to file 
fwrite($fp, $mytext) or die('Could not write to file.'); 
$content = file("C:/Users/jj/bob.txt");


// close file 
fclose($fp); 

?>
```

Both files do exist in the folder. I just cannot see any updates on bob.txt.

Is this a permission error in windows? It works fine on my laptop at home. I also cannot change the php files on my website, using filezilla.

Comment: two things. are you running the script on windows? and have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349469/changing-php-write-permissions-in-xampp-on-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

It may very well be a file permissions issue.

Try your code using a direct pointer to the file instead of a path to it, using the following code:

I added a `chmod` directive. See the comments above `chmod ($file, 0644);`

**Tested succesfully on my hosted WWW website**:

```
<?php 

// create file pointer 

$file = "bob.txt";
$fp = fopen($file, 'w') or die('Could not open file, or fike does not exist and failed to create.'); 

// chmod ($file, 0777); // or use 0777 if 0644 does not work
chmod ($file, 0644);

$mytext = '<b>hi. This is my test</b>'; 

// write text to file 
fwrite($fp, $mytext) or die('Could not write to file.'); 
$content = file("bob.txt");

// close file 
fclose($fp); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have to set the permission from bob.txt to 0777 (or something else). In FileZilla it is very easy, because you can just check the permissions you want.