# PHP config file transfer variables?

Tags: php, config, document-root

I'm a php noob, so bear with me...

I have two files here. Both are in the SAME directory

I have a config file:

config.php

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

define('APP_NAME',"/control");
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/');
define('SITE_NAME', 'http://localhost/');
define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].APP_NAME);
?>
```

Then I have my index file:

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
require ('config.php');
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='".DOCUMENT_ROOT."/scripts/jquery.js"'></script>;
?>
.....THE REST OF MY HTML.....
```

But I get an error that "DOCUMENT_ROOT" is undefined. Why is it not pulling the value from the config.php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line: (missing ending quote `"` after `</script>` and `$` sign in front of `DOCUMENT_ROOT`)

I tested the following on my server and the script did load, since I do have `jquery.js` on mine.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='".DOCUMENT_ROOT."/scripts/jquery.js"'></script>;
```

to:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='$DOCUMENT_ROOT/scripts/jquery.js'></script>";
```

or:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='".DOCUMENT_ROOT."/scripts/jquery.js'></script>";
```

Comment: This helps but now I get "Not allowed to load local resource"

Comment: Give me a few minutes. @bagofmilk

Comment: I've been reading somewhere that it has to do with xampp permissions but nobody explains any further than that.

Comment: Ok. I don't have the capabilities to load everything you're using, however my server did not generate any errors when I removed the `$` in `src='$DOCUMENT_ROOT` can you try replacing `src='$DOCUMENT_ROOT` in my answer with `src='DOCUMENT_ROOT` @bagofmilk - Noticed your other comment. I don't know anything about `xampp`

Comment: I get this error: ( GET http://localhost/control/DOCUMENT_ROOT/scripts/jquery.js 404 (Not Found) ). my code has this:  echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='DOCUMENT_ROOT/scripts/jquery.js'></script>";

Comment: I kind of figured. When doing it the original way as I posted, I got this back in my server `<script type='text/javascript' src='/scripts/jquery.js'></script>` and I could see the jQuery file in the source when clicking on it in FF 26.0 - This is in using `src='$DOCUMENT_ROOT` @bagofmilk

Comment: So for some weird reason i changed require ('config.php') to --> require 'config'.php and it worked. I removed the parenthesis HOWEVER, it still gives me an error that it cannot load from local resource. Is this a permissions issue? If so, how do I go about editing this?

Comment: Maybe you can't use the word `DOCUMENT_ROOT` to define, it could be a reserved method. @bagofmilk - but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Also, you may not be able to use `DEFINED` words for JS, but I could be wrong. @bagofmilk

Comment: Is your desired output to be `/control/scripts/jquery.js` by any chance? @bagofmilk

Comment: Try this `echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='".DOCUMENT_ROOT."/scripts/jquery.js'></script>";` @bagofmilk - that echo'ed my whole server's path.

Comment: That works But it says it cannot load local resource. So its finding the file, but says it is not allowed to load it.

Comment: The above echo'ed `<script type='text/javascript' src='/var/user1/public_html/control/js/jquery.js'></script>` @bagofmilk

Comment: Ok, well that must surely have something to do with your system's settings. @bagofmilk

Comment: I changed my windows settings so that all users have full control and still get the error. Its a xampp thing and I cannot find anything anywhere to help

Comment: I'm Googling as we speak. @bagofmilk If I find something relevant, I'll let you know.

Comment: And what if you added `public` (depending on the name of your public folder) and change both your `http://localhost/` in your config to `http://localhost/public/`? @bagofmilk

Comment: A few things that I found was (in your config file) Instead of `http://localhost/` try `http://127.0.0.1` or just `localhost/` @bagofmilk - and any luck with what I also wrote just above?

Comment: my public folder is "control" and its defining the path just fine, it just will not open the file due to a permission. The path it finds is: `http://localhost/control/scripts/jquery.js` which is correct, so the php code is correct - something to do with the xampp permissions I think.

Comment: Are all your folders writeable? @bagofmilk For example `777`

Comment: All users have full control of all folders/files in the C:\ drive

Comment: These answers on SO may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349612/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12656964/1415724 - And as for the config settings instead of `http://localhost/` can you try the actual drive path? I.e.: `C:\drive\control\` ? or something to that affect. @bagofmilk

Comment: I guess my main problem here is that my scripts and styles are not being referenced when the user goes to a php page inside a child folder. If anyone knows a way around this, that would be great. My assumption was that I need to define the root directory - but that turned into xampp not letting me load local files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dereference your variable using $:

```
$DOCUMENT_ROOT
```

That is assuming it's been properly defined in the server environment.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small syntax error at the end of your echo, otherwise it works fine for me.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='".DOCUMENT_ROOT."/scripts/jquery.js\"'></script>";
```

Comment: Now I get "Not allowed to load local resource"...but it did remove the DOCUMENT_ROOT error

Comment: Did you escape the double quotes after jquery.js using \ ?

Comment: I used this: (echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='".DOCUMENT_ROOT."/scripts/jquery.js\"'></script>";) and the error its reference is this: (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/control/scripts/jquery.js%22). It is encoding the backslash as "%22"