# Permission denied when starting codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, permissions, windows-7-x64

When am trying to open codeigniter home page i found this message

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: require(C:\wamp\www\ci\system\core\Security.php)[function.require]:failed to open stream: Permission denied
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 145
```

and i tried to change the permission of the logged user and i give it full control to Security php page and i tried to run wamp as administrator but the problem still existing, so how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is a file server problem: You don't have read permission required to open the file. Check this answer to know how to change them:

[changing php write permissions in XAMPP on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349469/changing-php-write-permissions-in-xampp-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

check your C:\wamp\www\ci\system\core\Security.php file exist or not ?

Comment: its exist, when tried to open it, pop up message with page can't open appear

Answer (score -1):

finally i have found the answer to this question ^_^
i just clean my PC from malewares and restart it again, and finally give all users permission to read, write and edit the Security.php Security_helper.php files which are files in System folder in codeigniter source, thank you all for your replay