# Access Forbidden on Form Submission 403

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp, http-status-code-403

There's definitely versions of this question out there, but none of them helped me solve my problem.

I'm prelearning PHP for a subject I'm taking this semester and I was testing a simple w3Schools example html file that goes like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // collect value of input field
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['fname']); 
    if (empty($name)) {
        echo "Name is empty";
    } else {
        echo $name;
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I get to the point where I submit the form, I get the 403 error. If I just echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] it gives me the file name fine, it's just that if I put anything in the "action" section, I get the 403. I've tried configuring a virtual host and setting these properties

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\site1"
ServerName site1
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\site1">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To no avail, I saw another post about urlencoding, but that shouldn't matter if I'm accessing local files should it? Any ideas or suggestions appreciated :)

Posted below is the error:

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either
>   read-protected or not readable by the server.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403
>
> site1 Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.28

Note I'm using xampp on windows 7 to do this.

**EDIT:** Reinstalling fixed the problem. I suppose it's possible that I broke something while editing the config files, would like to have known what it was that gave me a 403 though.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells exactly what the problem is. Try changing your file permission on your project. Try this [changing php write permissions in XAMPP on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349469/changing-php-write-permissions-in-xampp-on-windows-7)

Comment: Usually, when XAMP is installed in `c:\xampp` (or anywhere outside `c:\program files`) there is no permission problem

Comment: Yep, I have installed it in c:\xampp, and naturally all permissions were allowed for all users (just me). I still have the error, I've tried running xampp as administrator... you know, all the usual things when you get permission errors on windows

Answer (score 0):

Might be abit late, but I faced a similar problem today while trying to submit a form through POST. It would not allow me to submit a string that had a link and would through a 403 Forbidden Acess Denied error.

Disabling modsecurity (I did this from the control panel) solved it!