# WordPress on XAMPP Windows - "The upgrade directory exists but is not writable."

Tags: wordpress, windows, permissions, xampp

I'm running WordPress locally on a **Windows 11** machine using XAMPP.

Under Site Health Status, I get the following message:

> The `wp-content/upgrade` directory exists but is not writable. This directory is used for plugin and theme updates. Please make sure the server has write permissions to this directory.

I am trying to fix this error but everything I've tried so far have failed.

Here are the things I've tried:

**PHP safe mode**
PHP safe mode is off.

**WordPress `upload_path` and `upload_url_path` options**
Both are empty.

**Changing file permissions**
WordPress is installed at the root of a non-system drive (`F:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress`). I have changed the permission of the entire WordPress folder structure so that the user `Everyone` has `Full control`.

I'd like to add that this is a fresh install of Windows, XAMPP and WordPress. I haven't messed around with any server settings or file permissions. **Moreover, WordPress can download and install themes/plug-ins by itself without any issue.** However, it fails to remove any themes/plug-ins and I've to delete them manually from the `wp-content` folder.

I am wondering what the issue is and if someone is able to help me out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [changing php write permissions in XAMPP on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349469/changing-php-write-permissions-in-xampp-on-windows-7) You need to change the Windows protection on your WordPress install directories and files so the apache web server (which runs php for you) can write to them as well as read them.

Comment: @O.Jones I have followed the instructions there and changed the file permissions so that `Everyone` has `Full control`. But the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the **portable** version of Xampp or, instead, you've installed the ordinary version of this stack, simply changing the default folder from C:\xampp to F:\xampp? Sorry to say, but installing a non-portable version of Xampp in a folder different than C:\xampp is absolutely unreliable!

I suggest you using the portable version of this stack. After unziping it, its advisable to rename the folder xampp to a more specific name, related to PHP version. Example: xampp56, xampp74, xampp82. Doing so will enable you using more than one version of Xampp in your computer (one at a time).

After doing that, double click the file "setup_xampp.bat" to reconfigure the entire package to this new (and non standard) path.

About the Windows 11 permissions: have you tried to give Full control over the entire F: disk? I use a Xampp 5.6 and a Xampp 8.1 (portable version) installed in a D: disk of my computer, where all users have Full control over the entire disk.